# layout is showing fine in design mode but not in real device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appcompat, android-constraintlayout

Hello I have an issue with my layout. Its working properly on preview mode and on an emulator with Api level 24 but when I run it on a device with api 19 it just breaks up and gets all messed up. Even my edit text fields end up unresponsive. here I paste my XML code to see if you guys coud help me out.

EDIT: I am very sorry I've pasted the wrong code (it was incomplete). I have edited and now its correct. Also attached a couple of pictures of how looks in the named devices.
[Here is the messed layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kz80K.png) [And here is the correct one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42adM.png)
.Another thing is that I am using one nested constraint layout. Do you thing that could be it?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    tools:context="com.cuantomefalta.cuantomefalta.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/weighing3"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/little_square"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/cero_percent"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/weighing2"
        tools:text="25%"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/grade3"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/little_square"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/one"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/weighing3"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/converted3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/weighing3"
        tools:text="100" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/converted3"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/little_square"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/one_point_cero"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/weighing3"
        tools:text="8.5"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/weighing2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/little_square"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/cero_percent"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/weighing1"
        tools:text="25%"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/grade2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/little_square"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/one"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/weighing2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/converted2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/weighing2"
        tools:text="100" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/converted2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/little_square"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/one_point_cero"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/weighing2"
        tools:text="8.5"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/weighing1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/little_square"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/cero_percent"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/weighing"
        tools:text="25%"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/grade1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/little_square"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/one"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/weighing1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/converted1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/weighing1"
        tools:text="100"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/converted1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/little_square"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/one_point_cero"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/weighing1"
        tools:text="8.5"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/weighing"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/little_square"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/cero_percent"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="25%"

        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/grade"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/little_square"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/one"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/weighing"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/converted"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/weighing"
        tools:text="100" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/converted"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/little_square"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/one_point_cero"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/weighing"
        tools:text="1.0" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-2505831397151341/8310107897"
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        ads:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/shareView"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/big_circle"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/adView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">


        <TextSwitcher
            android:id="@+id/final_grade"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="234dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="-12dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="125sp"
                tools:text="55" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="-12dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="125sp"
                tools:text="99" />
        </TextSwitcher>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/goalGrade"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/little_circle"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:text="@string/five"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            tools:text="@string/five"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/first_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:text="@string/me_faltan"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/shareView"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/second_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:text="@string/para_llegar"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/goalGrade"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/shareView"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/floatingActionButton8"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/floatingActionButton8"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_clear_white_24dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/floatingActionButton9"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/floatingActionButton9"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_delete_sweep_white_24dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/floatingActionButton10"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/floatingActionButton10"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/shareView"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_play_arrow_white_24dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/shareView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/shareView"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_share_white_24dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post screenshots of how it should look vs. how it looks?

Comment: Make sure that all your views that are direct children of the `ConstraintLayout` are constraint horizontally and vertically. I can tell you that your `TextSwitcher` is not constrained vertically. I would also change the top constraint for the `TextView` "first_text" to "parent" rather than the id of the `ConstraintLayout`. Try these things to see if your issues resolve. (They are good things to do regardless.)

Comment: Hello I have posted the screen shots @damian As you requested

Comment: @Cheticamp they are all constraint. I just pasted wrong my code. Now is complete if you would like still help me out and take a look. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your display resolution might be the problem.

Comment: Hello @Ognjen Stanojevic Why this should be an issue if all my units are in dp? aren't those independet of the density of the screens?

Answer (score 0):

Check in the build.gradle(module App) for the  minSdkVersion &        targetSdkVersion, your device might not be in the range, if so correct that

Comment: Hello @LaideLawal this is not the problem my min sdk is 16 and my target is 26 so it should be fine to run on api 19 devices